# Obtaining an IEnumerable from HttpPost

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to create an IEnumerable from an HttpPost request.

The JSON in the body reads as follows:

```
[{"id":15496,"order":0},{"id":15500,"order":1},{"id":15503,"order":2}]
```

The post request is like so:

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public IActionResult SendReorderRows([FromBody] IEnumerable<ReorderRow> rows){
         foreach(var row in rows){
             Debug.WriteLine(row.id);
         }
    }
```

The referenced class is here:

```
    public class ReorderRow
    {
        public int id;
        public int order;
    }
```

However when I run this example it gives me the

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

error for "rows".

I'm having difficulty finding a basic way to parse JSON and convert it to an IEnumerable for use in the API. Am I missing something straightforward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array instead.

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public IActionResult SendReorderRows([FromBody] ReorderRow[] rows) {
     foreach(var row in rows){
         Debug.WriteLine(row.id);
     }
}
```

It will bind to the JSON array.

You also need public properties in the object model in order for them to be properly populated when binding the objects.

```
public class ReorderRow {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core : How model binding works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#how-model-binding-works)